# How to implement floor, ceil and round in LLVM bitcode?

Tags: math, compiler-construction, llvm, primitive

I'm writing the maths functions for a small LLVM-based programming language,
and I'm currently stumped by how to implement the common rounding functions floor, ceil and round (to even). Firstly because I haven't found any algorithm descriptions for these functions, secondly because I'm not familiar with what capabilities LLVM has w. rounding.

Being able to round negative numbers correctly is a must, rounding to a specific precision is not. Rounding to an integral value will do. Simply being pointed to any existing implementations that can be used from LLVM bitcode will also work.

Comment: Not really an answer, otherwise I'd make it so. But just anecdotal information. I have found that when I'm in such a position, I will write the C code to reproduce that function, and then compile it with clang or llvm-gcc and look at the resulting llvm ir. This usually gives me a good enough idea as to how I should proceed.

Comment: This might be slightly offtopic, but i think it's still valuable to know and consider when implementing your own math library: coming up with an algorithm for those functions that works correctly with the quirks of floating point math is not as trivial as it might seem first, as can be seen e.g. [here](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/01/27/theres-only-four-billion-floatsso-test-them-all/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to start with the [LLVM language reference manual](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html).

You might start by implementing `trunc( )` like something along these lines (warning, don't actually use this; it's intended as an example, and isn't correct.  See discussion below):

```
define float @trunc(float %x) {
    %rounded = fptosi float %x to i32
    %asFloat = sitofp i32 %rounded to float
    ret float %asFloat
}
```

The `fptosi ... to ...` instruction is documented as rounding a floating-point value to an integer value according to the round-to-zero rounding mode.  The `sitofp ... to ...` instruction converts that value back into a floating-point value to return.

However, there is a problem with this implementation; reading the language reference that I linked to, "the behavior of `fptosi ... to ...` is undefined if the result of rounding to the nearest integer cannot fit in the destination type."

This is pretty easy to work around, though, because all sufficiently large floating-point numbers are already integers, and don't need to be rounded; if the absolute value of `x` is greater than or equal to 2^23, you can just return x itself.

(This is all for single precision; for double, you will likely want to use `i64`, and you will need to use a threshold of 2^52)

For the other operations, like `floor` and `round`, you can begin with `trunc`, then check the residual `x - trunc(x)` and adjust the result accordingly.

Alternatively, you could call out to your host platform's C library, which already includes these functions.  This is an approach taken by many programming languages.

Comment: Calling out to my local C library is a good idea. However according to the LLVM lang. ref. fptosi rounds towards 0, not towards nearest.

Comment: @voxcogitatio: excellent point; shows how carefully I skimmed the reference as I was writing that snippet.  I'll correct it later today.

Answer (score 1):

If you look on Google Code Search, there are a few [results](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#xQlobzjVCWM/s_floor.c&q=floor%20lang:c&sa=N&cd=2&ct=rc). The linked example assumes IEEE floating point numbers. Ordinarily, compilers for common PCs just compile `floor` to floating point instructions. For example the original 387 arithmetic processor has the instruction `FPREM` which more or less does a piece of what you need for `floor`.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented floor for float vectors the following way: 'truncate' the value x, then compare x and trunc(x). Where trunc(x)>x, subtract 1, because floor(x) must be always at most x.
I have coded this in Haskell. I do not know, whether this helps you. See floorLogical in
http://code.haskell.org/~thielema/llvm-extra/src/LLVM/Extra/Vector.hs

Round to even is generally expensive and not of much use. I simply use floor(x+0.5).
In SSE4.1 there are also roundss, roundps et.al.